Is spotting a hiding foe a passive Contest?
A goblin fires an arrow from a cluttered area, then, using its "Nimble Escape" feature, hides in the clutter. It rolls a Stealth check of 12.
A PC wants to go after it. The PC has a Passive perception of 12.
Does the PC automatically see it? Is passively seeing a hiding opponent a meet-or-beat thing, or is it a Contest in which a tie means the status quo is maintained (i.e. hider wins)?
Of course, the PC could do a Search action instead of their attack, and if they roll well, spot the goblin, but since that replaces the PC's attack, they would be at the mercy of another shoot-and-hide combo from the goblin again. Is this correct?

On the goblin's turn, it attempts to Hide.
The rules for this are in the Hiding Sidebar of the Using Your Abilities rules, and do state that the goblin's Stealth is opposed by the PC's Passive Perception.

Passive Perception. When you hide, there's a chance someone will notice you even if they aren't searching. To determine whether such a creature notices you, the DM compares your Dexterity (Stealth) check with that creature's passive Wisdom (Perception) score, which equals 10 + the creature's Wisdom modifier, as well as any other bonuses or penalties.

Although this is not explicitly stated to be a contested check, it certainly meets the definition of one:

Sometimes one character's or monster's efforts are directly opposed to another's...
This situation also applies when one of them is trying to prevent the other one from accomplishing a goal...
Both participants in a contest make ability checks appropriate to their efforts.

Ties in contested checks maintain the status quo
The rules for Contested Checks say:

If the contest results in a tie, the situation remains the same as it was before the contest.

Before the goblin attempted to Hide, the PC knew where it was*.  Because the contest resulted in a tie, that situation does not change.  The PC still knows where it is*.  The PC does not have to resort to Searching on its turn.
However, the goblin would still be Hidden from other creatures, if they had a Passive Perception of 11 or worse.

*I have deliberately used 'knew where the Goblin was / knows where the goblin is' rather than saying that the PC 'sees the Goblin', as the question was originally framed by OP.  Note that for the Goblin to even attempt to Hide from the PC, it must not be able to be seen clearly.  The Nimble Escape feature permits the Goblin to Hide as a bonus action, but does not grant the ability to Hide in Plain Sight, and if the PC can still clearly see the Goblin, its attempt to Hide will automatically fail.  OP has said that the room is filled with clutter, so presumably the Goblin has many objects behind which it can Hide.  If the Goblin is thus permitted an attempt to Hide, in no event will the PC (clearly) see the Goblin, whether the Hide attempt is successful or not.  Instead, a successful Hide here means that the PC has 'lost track' of where the Goblin might be among the clutter, while a failed Hide (as in the case presented) means that the PC still knows the location of the goblin, even though it can't be clearly seen.  Perhaps it is making noise or is visibly moving the clutter as it passes.  It could be seen 'unclearly' (perhaps in glimpses through the clutter), but not necessarily.

What I find interesting about this is it sort of deviates from a general rule that ties go to the person rolling. For example, if an enemy's armor class is 16 then an attack roll of 16 hits. Likewise, if an enemy's spell DC is 16, a save of 16 will pass. This is a sort of edge case where the tie doesn't go to the roller.

@Pyrotechnical Well, in a contested ability check, by definition, both people are 'rolling' (even if in this case that is obscured by the fact that one of them is using a Passive score in place of a roll).  I wouldn't call it an edge case as much as 'different kind of check'.  For attack rolls ties hit but a 1 always misses.  For saves a tie saves, but a 1 doesn't necessarily fail.  For a skills check a tie 'succeeds', but for a contested skill check a tie doesn't change the dituation.  It's apples and oranges.
